# Create vhost conf

Tags: apache

I want to configure a vhost for php so that my open base dir restriciton is overwritten but it does not use my vhost.conf.

My `php.ini` always shows `open_basedir /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/:/tmp/  ||||` no value last value is global but local has a value. I want to overwrite this with the following vhost.conf which is lying under `/var/www/vhosts/domain/conf`

```
<Directory /srv/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs>
AllowOverride All
php_admin_value open_basedir none
</Directory>
```

Its not a subdomain.

```
ls -al
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root psaserv   295 2011-09-30 19:43 vhost.conf
```

Steps to reproduce:

```
login as root
cd /var/www/vhosts/domain/conf
touch vhost.conf
added content
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/websrvmng --reconfigure-vhost --vhost-name=domain
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

no change :(

I am using ubuntu with plesk.

Comment: I'd love to know how you got this working, if you did

Comment: @Androidewbie is `/srv/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs` a typo or is actually what you have in your vhost.conf?

Answer (score 1):

Did you include your new conf file in httd.conf?

Try adding this line to the end of httpd.conf:

```
Include /var/www/vhosts/domain/conf/vhost.conf
```

and then restart apache